# Can't print list of places

Tags: flutter, dart

Why i can't print all of List. I was debug the project, every data has map to list but i still can print it out. Please help me.

Here my Screen to show the list

```
class MapScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const MapScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        FutureProvider(
          create: (context) => GeolocatorService().getLocation(),
          initialData: null,
        ),
        ProxyProvider<Position, Future<List<Place>>>(
          update: (context, position, places) {
            return PlacesService()
                .getPlaces(position.latitude, position.longitude);
          },
        )
      ],
      child: const MaterialApp(
        home: GetScreen(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class GetScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const GetScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final currentPosition = Provider.of<Position?>(context);
    if (currentPosition != null) {
      final placeService = Provider.of<Future<List<Place>>>(context);
      FutureProvider(
        create: (context) => placeService,
        initialData: const [],
        child: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              leading: IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                  },
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios_new_rounded)),
              title: const Text('Tìm nhà hàng'),
              elevation: 0,
              backgroundColor: Colors.purple,
              centerTitle: true,
            ),
            // ignore: unnecessary_null_comparison
            body: Consumer<List<Place>>(
              builder: (context, places, child) {
                return Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    SizedBox(
                      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 3,
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                      child: GoogleMap(
                        initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
                            target: LatLng(currentPosition.latitude,
                                currentPosition.longitude),
                            zoom: 16.0),
                        zoomGesturesEnabled: true,
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 10.0,
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                        child: ListView.builder(
                            itemCount: places.length,
                            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                              return Card(
                                child: ListTile(
                                  title: Text(
                                    places[index].name,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              );
                            }))
                  ],
                );
              },
            )),
      );
    }
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          leading: IconButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
              icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios_new_rounded)),
          title: const Text('Tìm nhà hàng'),
          elevation: 0,
          backgroundColor: Colors.purple,
          centerTitle: true,
        ),
        body: const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()));
  }
}
```

Here my code to get data and map them to list. After the code map data to list done, i didn't see the code comeback to MapScreen().

```
class PlacesService {
  final key = 'AIzaSyDM32Kzq-Pz_MPorUAYxWgDX7qb3nt2S6M';

  Future<List<Place>> getPlaces(double lat, double lng) async {
    var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(
        'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=$lat,$lng&type=restaurant&rankby=distance&key=$key '));
    var json = convert.jsonDecode(response.body);
    var jsonResults = json['results'] as List;
    return jsonResults.map((place) => Place.fromJson(place)).toList();
  }
}

class Place {
  final Geometry geometry;
  final String name;
  final double rating;
  final int userRatingCount;
  final String vicinity;

  Place(this.geometry, this.name, this.rating, this.userRatingCount,
      this.vicinity);

  Place.fromJson(Map<dynamic, dynamic> parsedJson)
      : geometry = Geometry.fromJson(parsedJson['geometry']),
        name = parsedJson['name'],
        rating = (parsedJson['rating'] != null)
            ? (parsedJson['rating'])!.toDouble()
            : 0.0,
        userRatingCount = (parsedJson['user_ratings_total'] != null)
            ? parsedJson['user_ratings_total']
            : 0,
        vicinity = parsedJson['vicinity'];
}
```

And the Screen is return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())) all the time.

[The screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nz6Fx.jpg)

Edit 1: After i put return in , i got another error :  Could not find the correct Provider<List> above this Consumer<List> Widget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot `return`:

```
if (currentPosition != null) {
      final placeService = Provider.of<Future<List<Place>>>(context);
      return FutureProvider( // Add return there
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! But when i add return, i have another error Could not find the correct Provider<List<Place>> above this Consumer<List<Place>> Widget